# How to fetch the highest category in the hierachry for a specific post?

Tags: categories

I understand Wordpress concept "primary category", but **I do not understand how to fetch the name of the highest category in the hierarchy** for a specific post?

Having this code:

```
$category_obj = get_the_category( $post_id );
$category_name = $category_obj[0]->cat_name;
```

would fetch the category's name of the post, but this category is only the first category listed for the post and that category is not always the primary category.

I'm using this outside of "the loop".

Comment: the is no such thing as primary category in wordpress

Comment: @MarkKaplun - the first category then :-) Sorry for not knowing the terminology correctly.

Comment: the problem is there is no such thing as "first" in the context of post terms. Most likely whatever will be "first" is just either what was created first, or based on sort by category name, neither will usually be what you will consider as "primary", at least not always

Comment: based on your answer, maybe you meant the highest category in the hierarchy? or maybe just the one used in the url for a specific permalink structure?

Comment: @MarkKaplun - Yes I meant highest category in the hierarchy.

Comment: can you please edit the question, so I will be able to remove the downvote (if you care about it)

Comment: I have done that now! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea (which heavily depends on what you are viewing [single or archive] and also your taxonomy-structure) is to look for the term parent.

Maybe this can help you aswell ...

You were asking about "highest category in the hierarchy for a specific post".

Example:
A post is associated with **3 terms** of an taxonomy which are **hierachical**:

```
Parent Term
-First-Child Term
--Second-Child Term
```

You could get all the associated terms of this post:

```
$all_terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
```

And than find the term which has a **parent** of **0**:

```
foreach($all_terms as $term) {

   if($term->parent == 0){
      //here you have the data of the topmost parent, e.g. "Parent Term"

      // get parent term ID
      $parent_id = $term->term_id; 

      // get term obj from ID to get term name
      $parent_obj = get_term_by( 'id', $parent_id, $taxonomy );
      
      // show parent term name
      echo $parent_obj->name; // "Parent Term"

      // show parent term permalink URL
      echo = get_term_link( $parent_id );
   }

}
```

As you see, this will only work if the post has only one parent and than child-terms assiciated. For other setups this will not work!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I couldn't find any core functionaliy for this in Wordpress, but to retrieve the primary category you could use the get permalink function:

```
$site_url = get_site_url();
$post_slug = get_permalink( $post_id );
$post_slug_remove_siteurl = str_replace( $site_url, '', $post_slug);                           
$category_from_slug = explode ('/', $post_slug_remove_siteurl);
$category_name = $category_from_slug[1];
```

This requires you to have category included in your permalink. The reason why this is possible is that when changing primary category the permalink is changed as well:

```
<site-url> / <primary category> / <post name>
```

Please tell me if there are any better of achieving this!

Answer (score 0):

**Display Primary Category (Yoast's WordPress SEO)**

```
<?php
            // SHOW YOAST PRIMARY CATEGORY, OR FIRST CATEGORY
            $category = get_the_category();
            $useCatLink = true;
            // If post has a category assigned.
            if ($category) {
                $category_display = '';
                $category_link = '';
                if (class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {
                    // Show the post's 'Primary' category, if this Yoast feature is available, & one is set
                    $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term('category', get_the_id());
                    $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
                    $term = get_term($wpseo_primary_term);
                    if (is_wp_error($term)) {
                        // Default to first category (not Yoast) if an error is returned
                        $category_display = $category[0]->name;
                        $category_link = get_category_link($category[0]->term_id);
                    } else {
                        // Yoast Primary category
                        $category_display = $term->name;
                        $category_link = get_category_link($term->term_id);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Default, display the first category in WP's list of assigned categories
                    $category_display = $category[0]->name;
                    $category_link = get_category_link($category[0]->term_id);
                }
                // Display category
                if (!empty($category_display)) {
                    if ($useCatLink == true && !empty($category_link)) {
                        echo '<span class="post-category">';
                        echo '<a href="' . $category_link . '">' . htmlspecialchars($category_display) . '</a>';
                        echo '</span>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<span class="post-category">' . htmlspecialchars($category_display) . '</span>';
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```